# How to modify Notifier in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have problem with react-native-Notifier. I am trying to show notification using Notifier. If there are any better libraries, you can recommend. My problem is with the notch on the phone. By the time notification is showing up, it's hidden by notch.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXvMo.png

And code snippet. How can I solve this ?

```js
Notifier.showNotification({
                    title: "Error",
                    description: message,
                    Component: NotifierComponents.Alert,
                    showEasing: Easing.bounce,
                    componentProps:{
                        alertType: "error",
                        
                    },
                    containerStyle:{
                    },
                    duration: 4000,
                    showAnimationDuration: 800,
                    
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use prop `translucentStatusBar={true}` in options, It adds additional top padding that equals to StatusBar.currentHeight. (Android Only)
Hope it works, or you can consider this [react-native-flash-message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flash-message)

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution. If somebody will have same problem just use `CustomSafeAreaView` as a part of ContainerComponent.

```
const CustomSafeAreaView: React.FC<CustomSafeAreaViewProps> = ({ children, style }) => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
          ...(style || {}),
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };
  
  export default CustomSafeAreaView;
```

```
export const NotifySuccess = (title: string, message: string) : void => {
    Notifier.showNotification({
        title: title,
        description: message,
        Component: NotifierComponents.Alert,
        componentProps:{
            alertType: 'success',
            ContainerComponent: CustomSafeAreaView,
        },
```